# Decryption returns empty result - nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

```
function encrypt() {
  const iv = '3af545da025d5b07319cd9b2571670ca'
    , payload = '01000000000000000000000000000000'
    , key = 'c1602e4b57602e48d9a3ffc1b578d9a3';

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes128', new Buffer(key, 'hex'), new Buffer(iv, 'hex'));
  const encryptedPayload = cipher.update(new Buffer(payload, 'hex'));

  let encryptedPayloadHex = encryptedPayload.toString('hex');
  console.log(encryptedPayloadHex); // returns 'ae47475617f38b4731e8096afa5a59b0'
};

function decrypt() {
  const iv = '3af545da025d5b07319cd9b2571670ca'
    , key = 'c1602e4b57602e48d9a3ffc1b578d9a3'
    , payload = 'ae47475617f38b4731e8096afa5a59b0';

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes128', new Buffer(key, 'hex'), new Buffer(iv, 'hex'));
  const decryptedPayload = decipher.update(new Buffer(payload, 'hex'), 'hex', 'hex');      

  console.log(decryptedPayload); // returns empty string
  // decipher.update(new Buffer(payload, 'hex')) // returns empty buffer

  const decryptedPayloadHex = decipher.final('hex'); // returns 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt' error
  // console.log(decryptedPayloadHex);
};
```

The decryption result, though, is always empty.

The nodejs docs state that `update` returns the value as string in given encoding, if provided, otherwise as Buffer. Nevertheless I tried using `final` as well, but no success.

P.S. In fact, I receive the `encryptedPayload` value and the `iv` from external source (they're not encrypted and generated by me), but I decided to test out the encryption (I have the plain `payload` value) and my encryption returns the same result as the one that I'm receiving externally.

Comment: The PHP script was given to me, so that I can use it for testing purposes while developing the node.js script, so that I can check that the decrypted result is correct. The point of the OP is to find out why the JS code doesn't decrypt correctly. The focus isn't on the PHP code...

Comment: Aside: The whole scenerio is a little crazy since in general the IV does not need to be secret, the secret is in the key.

Comment: @zaph, I found out that actually the encryption of the data is not done by PHP code but directly on the hardware that generates the data. Therefore the padding, I guess, is not a problem.

Comment: This is the second time you've asked this question and it still doesn't really make sense.

Comment: No, the first one didn't make much sense and I closed it, but here I've got the problem structured out. And there are the strings to test it out with. What's there that doesn't make sense (except for that I have to use the first encryption result as an IV for the decryption, but I pointed out the reasons for that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem turned out to be the padding. I got inspiration [from here.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2794#issuecomment-139436581) I simply added

```
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
```

right after I crete the `decipher` object.

That is weird though, because padding problems could occur when encryption is done in one language and decryption in another, but should not happen when encryption and decryption are done in the same language (as I did my testing here)... If anyone has comments on the padding issue - please add them, so that future viewers can gain knowledge (as well as me).

Comment: The problem is that unless the plain text is always an exact multiple of the block size padding must be added.

Comment: Well, the plain text is 16 bytes and the block size of AES-128 is 128 bits (which is 16 bytes), which makes the text exact multiple of the block size. So, this makes me even more confused.

Comment: If the plain text is **always 16 bytes** no padding is needed for AES. Different implementations in the same or a different language may have a different padding settings. It is best to explicitly set the padding type.